# How can I select rows where number went down as date went up

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I have a program at a repair shop and I want to select all of the cars in my RepairOrder table where the mileage of the later repair order is less than the mileage of the prior repair order, how can I build that select statement?

```
ID  VehicleID  Mileage  RepairDate
01  1          18425    2013-08-13
02  1          28952    2013-02-26
03  2          22318    2012-08-27
04  3          21309    2012-08-07
05  3          16311    2012-02-27
06  3          16310    2012-02-11
07  4          11098    2011-03-23
08  5          21309    2012-08-07
09  5          16309    2012-02-27
10  5          16310    2012-02-11
```

In this case I should only be selecting VehicleID 1 because it has a RepairDate that is greater then the previous row, but a Mileage that is less than the previous row. There could also be 3 rows with the same vehicle and the middle date has a mileage of 3 or 5000000, and I will need to select those VehicleID's as well.

Results from using the LEAD() function

```
ID  RepairDate  Mileage
25  2011-12-23  45934
48  2009-02-26  13
48  2009-04-24  10
71  2011-07-26  31163
71  2015-01-13  65656
```

Comment: I dont understand your 3 rows sample, could you elaborate or include it on the sample data as car 5. Also what rdbms are you using?

Comment: I am using Sql server with ssms, and I just added the data for you. So the query should also select vehicleID 5 since the middle repair has a mileage that is less than the row before it. And I also should've said 3 or more rows. There could be 10 repair orders for 1 vehicle, and 1 of the mileages is screwed up and I need to flag it.

Comment: what version of sql server? so this is just to detect data error. But then you want VehiculeID or ID where error happen?

Comment: Why same vehicle, for example, vehicleID 1, has different mileage, and more curious, according to the repairDate, the mileage of the same vehicleID (1) in a later RepairDate, is less than previous repairDate, im confusing.

Comment: Hi from Venezuela @JuanRuizdeCastilla OP say is to flag errors, my guess data entry.

Comment: What version of SQL Server please, so I know what syntax is available?

Answer (score 2):

This is a great place to use [LEAD()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx) function for sql 2014+

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f4803/8)

```
WITH NextM as (
    SELECT 
       * , 
       LEAD(Mileage, 1, null) over (partition by VehicleID order by RepairDate) NextMileage
    FROM RepairOrder
) 
SELECT *
FROM NextM
WHERE Mileage > NextMileage
```

My solution show all columns so you can check what row have the problem.

Also I avoid using `distinct` because as OP suggest there may be several mistake for same car and this way you can see it all.
[image]

Comment: `LEAD()` is also available in 2012

Comment: @mheptinstall You are right. First line in [_microsoft page_](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx) say Apply to 2014+ but then next paragrah say `Applies to: SQL Server (SQL Server 2012 through current version) , `

Comment: These definitely aren't the right results. Some vehicleID's only appear once, and some of the other VehicleId's that appear twice have a greater mileage on the greater date, and other VehicleId's that appear twice have a smaller mileage on the greater date.   These are the first few results returned.

Comment: Tell me what result specific you think is wrong? I add a picture to help you describe the issue.

Comment: That result is in your comment is your desire output? If that is the case don't use comment just update your question and mention that in the comment. You can do better format there. Because I tought your rules will result in only 2 rows. I think will be better if you show your desire output and explain why.

Comment: I posted the result I got from this in the post since I couldn't seem to format it correctly here.

Comment: But that data isn't on the sample you provide :(. Can you edit the sqlFiddle and add those row? After you build the schema and run the query share the link.

Comment: I tried to add a more realistic example in the fiddle based on our current database results.

Comment: Also, this query takes about 6 minutes to run on a big table full of millions of repair orders.

Comment: Can you show what index you have in table `RepairOrder` because more simple than this query cant be done.

Comment: Is ok that result. What result you want from that data?

Comment: Hello, I see you didnt accept any answer. Didnt work for you?

Answer (score 0):

It's not terribly efficient, but you could do a pairwise selection

```
select t1.VehicleID 
from table t1, table t2 
where t1.VehicleId = t2.VehicleId 
AND t1.Mileage > t2.Mileage 
AND t1.RepairDate < t2.RepairDate
```

There is likely a better solution as pair-wise selections get EXTREMELY SLOW, but this should work as-is.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct RO.VehicleID 
from RepairOrder RO 
where exists(select * 
             from RepairOrder 
             where ID != RO.ID 
             and VehicleID = RO.VehicleID and RepairDate > RO.RepairDate 
             and Mileage < RO.Mileage);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH RepairSeqs AS(
    SELECT
        DateSeq = Row_Number OVER (PARTITION BY VehicleID ORDER BY RepairDate),
        MileageSeq = Row_Number OVER (PARTITION BY VehicleID ORDER BY Mileage),
        *
    FROM
       dbo.RepairOrder
)
SELECT *
FROM RepairSeqs
WHERE DateSeq <> MileageSeq;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct t.VehicleId
from (
select t.*, LEAD(Mileage) OVER (Partition by VehicleId ORDER BY RepairDate) LeadMileageValue
from RepairOrder t
) t
where t.Mileage > t.LeadMileageValue
```

Comment: While this might be a awesome solution to the problem, please consider adding some clarification on why this is a good answer and what it does.